# Is it possible to upload a file which can auto run and reboot on a linux system

Tags: linux, file-upload, autorun

I want to upload a file which can auto run and reboot on a linux system.
Or atleast do some changes on the system.
Please provide some help.

Answer (score 0):

Use scp to copy the script to the device.

```
    scp myscript user@server:/tmp/myscript
```

Then run with ssh.

```
    ssh user@server 'sh /tmp/myscript'
```

Or if you don't want to enter the password, you can use certificate based authentication.

If you want it to periodically run automatically, configure the Linux system to run it as a cron job